Login button is invisible on Samsung Galaxy A52 5G
I'm experiencing an issue with the login page of my Android application. The problem occurs only on Samsung Galaxy A52 5G devices. Users have reported that the login button is not visible when they first open the application. However, the button appears if they rotate the screen or tap the eye button to show the password. On all other phones, the login page works flawlessly.
Could this be a Samsung bug, an Android bug, or an issue with my application?
I tried changing the button ID in the .xml file, thinking it could be an issue with autofill. I also attempted to change the button elevation to 1dp, but nothing worked. Additionally, I tried setting the button visibility to View.VISIBLE in the onCreate method, but it didn't solve the issue.
Layout code is quite usual:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/baner"
        style="@style/appBaner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_banner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_version"
        style="@style/appVersion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baner"
        tools:text="25.0 - testy" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_orange_24dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlSymmetry" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_text_input"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/text_login"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginTextForm"
                style="@style/TextInputEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_layout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_orange_24dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlSymmetry" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_text_input"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/text_password"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passTextForm"
                style="@style/TextInputEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_visibility_24"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/otp_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_layout"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_orange_24dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlSymmetry" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/otp_text_input"
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/text_otp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/otpTextForm"
                style="@style/TextInputEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this is login button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButtonForm"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:text="@string/button_login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/otp_layout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordLink"
        style="@style/appVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/loginButtonForm"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/loginButtonForm"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginButtonForm" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Without any details, it's hard to give a solution. Can you post your XML layout?

@dev.tejasb i've added my layout code

Your layout seems to be fine except for small height screens (where you should consider wrapping your root constraint layout into a nested scroll view). Maybe, you are changing the visibility of the button from the code!

I've been working on this bug for at least a month now. I've tested it, and it works perfectly on my device and on many emulators (around 30 different emulators, including 20 from Samsung). It seems to be a bug specific to this particular device, and I'm looking for any workaround.

I've also tried setting the button visibility to View.VISIBLE in the onCreate method, but it didn't solve the issue.
